# Missing argument 2 for CActiveRecord::setAttribute() in yii

Tags: php, yii

```
 <?php
class ProjectTest extends CDbTestCase
{
    public function testCRUD()
    {
        $newProject = new Project;
        $newProjectName = 'Test Project 1';
        $newProject->setAttribute(
                                array('name'=>$newProjectName,
                                      'description'=>'Test Project Number One',
                                      'create_time'=>'2010-01-01 00:00:00',
                                      'create_user_id'=> 1,
                                      'update_time'=>'2010-01-01 00:00:00',
                                      'update_user_id'=> 1,)
                                );
        $this->assertTrue($newProject->save(false));
    }
}
?>
```

I have a ar class named Project...in table these are the list of items i have ...I m trying to test whether this code inserts the data in to that table or not, using phpunit test in command line but it gives error (Missing argument 2 for CActiveRecord::setAttribute() ) any help

Comment: What the error says, you're missing a parameter, the function has two, not one.  http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#setAttribute-detail

Comment: you can see from code i defined $name = name & $value = $newProjectName and so on according to set attribute but why error i very new to this pls help whats the second argument pls help..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the wrong function (setAttribute) instead of setAttribute**s**. You should use setAttribute**s** if you want to fill the values of a Model object with an array.

Details [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CModel#setAttributes-detail)

setAttribute is used to set a specific value of a model and it takes two parameters, the attribute name and its value